# Fatal error while installation of orocrm

Tags: php, class, orocrm

I'm getting this error when trying to install [**orocrm**](http://www.orocrm.com/) :

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'True' as class name as it is reserved in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-application\vendor\oro\platform\src\Oro\Component\ConfigExpression\Condition\True.php
>   on line 10

Any idea what might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP7. For now OroCrm doesn't support PHP7.

You need to downgrade PHP to 5.6 version.